# use setText() on multiple labels using for loop in Java (Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created multiple labels in design mode and named them as lab_1, lab_2, lab_3 and so on.
Now I want to use setText() on them using a for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
   String var= "lab_"+i;
   var.setText(i);
}
```

This obviously didn't work. But I'm unable to think of something else. 
Is it possible to change the labels into an array of labels now(I haven't created them dynamically instead I created them from the design window.)
Any help?

Comment: Use `Array` of `JLabel` or `List` of `JLabel`s. Though if you knew, how you want to align these `JLabel`s on the View, then one can easily provide an answer. GUI Builder tend to make life tough on this aspect :-) Just a simple drawing of how the view should be, will help us provide a very simply answer

Comment: @toothie, Please remove the netbeans tag.  This has nothing to do with the IDE you're using, and all you'll do is redirect netbeans queries here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this??.

```
   String EMPTY_SPACE="";

    JLabel [] jLabels ={lab_1, lab_2, lab_3};

    for (int i = 0; i < jLabels.length; i++) {
        jLabels[i].setText(i+EMPTY_SPACE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the loop and focus on these two lines

```
String var= "lab_"+i;
var.setText(i);
```

you are trying to call `setText` on `var` which is a string. Since your title talk about `label` and your example about `setText`, I believe you want to set the text of `JLabel` using it [`setText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)) method.

To solve your issue, simply change your variable names.

---

Note that even if it will probably solve the compiler error (that you did not tell us you had) that you had, your program will probably not work as expected.

If you expect a concatenation of each string in your label, then at each `setText` call you must retrieve the actual text and concatenate.

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting. I have already created those JLabel, Now I simply want to use them in a for loop. I don't want to call  lab_1.setText(i); on all 20 of them.

Comment: @toothie then on what do you expect to call `setText` ? `String` does not have this method.

Comment: @toothie, It'll help if you heed his advice and get rid of the `(String).setText()` call attempt and most importantly, post your code regarding the labels.  Besides, Strings are immutable.

Comment: @tgm1024 I understand that about strings. I think you misunderstood my problem. Its solved now. Thanks

Comment: @toothie I did not misunderstand your problem as my sugggestion was to change your variable name. At beggining you were trying to call `setText` on a string variable which does not offer this method. I also give you advices in case you wanted to concatenate (but obviously this is not the case so this can be ignored). But your main problem was that you were trying to call `setText` on a string instead of an instance of `JLabel` which is in your case retrieve from an array of them. Isn't it ?